# user_photos List access in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, list, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

when I try retrieving Data from FacebookLogin with user_photos Permission, 
I get an error of access Token invalid 209.

I figured it is because i try to save the data in a non-typematching variable.

Could someone tell me how access the id of photos retrieved from Facebook?

```
        print(result["photos"])
```

Gives me:

```
     Optional({
         data =     (
            {
        "created_time" = "2015-07-26T20:57:23+0000";
        id = 920478361357710;
    },
            {
        "created_time" = "2015-02-14T20:24:23+0000";
        id = 961789147179683;
        name = "szlangini kickdown";
    },
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
let parmas = ["fields" : "id, name"]
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: parmas
        , HTTPMethod: "GET")

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        let listPhoto = result["data"]

        guard let unWrappedPhotos = listPhoto as? [AnyObject] else {
            return
        }

        for dict in unWrappedPhotos {
            guard let id = dict["id"] as? String  else {
                break
            }
            print(id)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Getting Error: Value of type 'Anyobject?'  has no member 'Generator'

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer: Still getting an error for subscription of String in an 'AnyObject?' I think one must declare unWrappedPhotos as an [String: [String:String]] somehow